# How do I Isolate an Event's Title/Time in a variable to display on Storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ekevent

Here's the full description of my problem: I am fetching the events of a calendar for a full day (i.e.today) and storing them in an array. How do I isolate the next relevant (one that has not passed) event's title and time from the array to display them separately as labels?
Here's my code:

```
//Load Calendar Events
    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted,
                                                                    NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
        NSLog(@"User has granted permission");
        // Get the appropriate calendar
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        // Create the start date components
        NSDateComponents *beginDayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        beginDayComponents.day = 0;
        NSDate *todayStart = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:beginDayComponents
                                                      toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                     options:0];

        // Create the end date components
        NSDateComponents *endDayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        endDayComponents.day = 0;
        NSDate *todayEnd = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:endDayComponents
                                                           toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                          options:0];

        // Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
        NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:todayStart
                                                                endDate:todayEnd
                                                              calendars:nil];

        // Fetch all events that match the predicate
        NSArray *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
        NSLog(@"Here are the events in the array, %@", events);



        } else {
            NSLog(@"User has not granted permission");
        }
    }];
```

Thanks in advance, and have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

As apple states in its EKEventStore-documentation you will have to sort your array first, so that the next pending event is at index 0.

> **Note**: Retrieving events from the Calendar database does not
>   necessarily return events in chronological order. To sort an array of
>   EKEvent objects by date, call sortedArrayUsingSelector: on the array,
>   providing the selector for the compareStartDateWithEvent: method.

I'd suggest you then just pick the EKEvent-Object at index 0 of your array and read the properties from it and set them on your label.

```
EKEvent *event = [events objectAtIndex:0];
yourTitleLabel.text = event.text;

NSDateFormatter *formatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateformat = @"dd.MM HH:mm";
yourDateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:event.startDate];
```

**Edit:**
You would sort your array *events* like this:

```
events = [events sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareStartDateWithEvent:)];
```

For this to work, you have to import **EventKit/EventKit.h**

Comment: Thanks! Could you just show me an example of how to sort the events in the array by date? I'm still new at this. But again, thank you!

Comment: I've added it to my answer, take a look.